# What is build_resource and resource in Devise Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Where can I change the validation to save, using the Devise gem? I found this form:

```
def create
  build_resource(sign_up_params)
  if resource.valid?
    super
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

But what I find is similar to this:

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question should be specific and your relevant code should be [minimal, complete, and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Devise is made to work with any model, it is not mandatory to be `User`. A very common example is to have `User` and `AdminUser`.

If Devise was hardcoded to as you showed (`User.new`), it means that it'd never work for a different model nor it would allow you to have more than a model signing in into your webapp. Knowing that, the `resource` represents the model that you have added `devise` to, and that's signing in. In your case:

```
 build_resource(sign_up_params) # will be the similar to user = User.new(sign_up_params)
 resource # will be an instance of User
 resource.valid? # will be the name as user.valid?
```

Since it's using `resource.valid?`, you just need to implement the validations within the model `User` or `AdminUser` without changing any code in Devise.